# Why send JWT tokens in the Authorization header rather than as payload?

Tags: node.js, jwt

It seems that the common practice is to send JWTs in the Authorization header and preceded by the "Bearer " string.

Why is this done this way, and why not simply send the token in the body of a post request? Is there a convenient way to verify the token in node when it's sent in the header?

Comment: https://jwt.io/introduction Does this answer your question? You can send it as a `payload`, `header` and `signature`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JWT bearer tokens contain sensitive information, because they allow anyone bearing the token to impersonate you. It thus makes sense to treat them with special caution and, for example, *not* write them into server logs, or not allow them in cross-origin requests.

But such special treatment is possible only if all involved parties know which parts of a request contain sensitive information. If the token was just part of the payload, only the sending client and the receiving application might know, but intermediate parties like proxies, server frameworks or browers would not. By contrast, everyone knows that the `Authorization` header always contains sensitive information. And for example, browsers will not make cross-origin requests with an `Authorization` header, unless a prior [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) with `Access-Control-Request-Headers: Authorization` was successful.

In other words: It makes sense if HTTP requests always contain certain kinds of information in the same place like a predefined header.

Answer (score 0):

That is [standard specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/standards) (Official Internet Protocol Standards)

`The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage`

One of the RFC spec. [rfc6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)
at `2.1.  Authorization Request Header Field` section

- image version
  [image]
- text version

```
2.1.  Authorization Request Header Field

  When sending the access token in the "Authorization" request header
  field defined by HTTP/1.1 [RFC2617], the client uses the "Bearer"
  authentication scheme to transmit the access token.

  For example:

    GET /resource HTTP/1.1
    Host: server.example.com
    Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM

  The syntax of the "Authorization" header field for this scheme
  follows the usage of the Basic scheme defined in Section 2 of
  [RFC2617].  Note that, as with Basic, it does not conform to the
  generic syntax defined in Section 1.2 of [RFC2617] but is compatible
  with the general authentication framework being developed for
  HTTP 1.1 [HTTP-AUTH], although it does not follow the preferred
  practice outlined therein in order to reflect existing deployments.
  The syntax for Bearer credentials is as follows:

    b64token    = 1*( ALPHA / DIGIT /
                      "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / "+" / "/" ) *"="
    credentials = "Bearer" 1*SP b64token

  Clients SHOULD make authenticated requests with a bearer token using
  the "Authorization" request header field with the "Bearer" HTTP
  authorization scheme.  Resource servers MUST support this method.
```

Token types are `Basic` & `Digest` also use as `Bearer`

[This guide](https://darutk.medium.com/the-simplest-guide-to-oauth-2-0-8c71bd9a15bb) easy to understand Token concept.

Comment: Please do NOT post pictures of text information. Instead quote the relevant part as text and add a link to the source.

Comment: @jps, I was linked `rfc6705` the source but it may be hard to find the image content. I updated my answer with two versions(image and text) now, thanks for your pointing.